# CSS table background is rounded but borders are squared

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a table that has rounded top borders on either side, but the rest of the table's borders are squared.

When I apply this CSS the border remain squared, but the `background-color` *does* get rounded off, which creates a weird look:

```
table {border-collapse:collapse}
th {border-top:1px solid red; width:70px}
th, td {text-align:left; background-color:#cccccc}
th.header1 {border-top:1px solid red; border-left:1px solid red; border-top-left-radius:20px}
th.header2 {border-top:1px solid red; border-right:1px solid red; border-top-right-radius:20px}
```

The result is this:
[image]

How do I 'round' the borders in the top left/right header cells please so that the red border follows the background?

Please see the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5832/4/) for a working example.

Comment: What browser are you using? In IE9 your fiddle is working fine.

Comment: something like this? but this require additional element http://jsfiddle.net/z5832/6/

Comment: Sorry should have said - its Firefox 22

Comment: Never bothered to check IE9 but yes 9/10 works correctly.  Very interesting...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because border collapsed with:

**CSS**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Look at [quick fix](http://jsfiddle.net/z5832/8/).

Comment: Very quick fix;  like it!

Comment: Although weirdly @Raymond Ramirez's solution still has the collapsed border but works fine... :-/

Comment: I take that last comment back, @Raymond's suggestion is in fact error-prone

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
   table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

to:

```
 table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YgQ96/)**

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved rather simply by assigning the border properties only to the `table tag` instead of assigning them to the `th tag` and `td tag`.

```
table {
    background: #ccc;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
th {
    width: 70px;
}
th, td {
    text-align: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Tomer123/z5832/9/

Answer (score -1):

Use the code in this way:

```css
table {border:collapse;}
th {border-top:1px solid red; width:70px}
th, td {text-align:left; background-color:#cccccc}
th.header1 {border-top:1px solid red; border-left:1px solid red; border-top-left-radius:20px}
```

Comment: @EvilDr, he use `border:collapse;` (invalid value for border property) this is set for `border-collapse` property default value (separate).

Comment: Ahhh I see.  So that declaration gets dropped because it is actually an error!  Thanks very much